# What is a generically reduced scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

I am reading the  book "3264 & All That
Intersection Theory in Algebraic Geometry". In the following definition (see page 30)

Definition 1.22. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a morphism of smooth varieties. We say a subvariety
$A \subset X$ is generically transverse to $f$  if the preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ is generically reduced
and...

What  is the  definition "generically reduced"? I can not  find this definition in  any part of this book.

Comment: I would say "generic" refers to the *generic point* of an irreducible scheme. However, "generic" is sometimes used to mean "general", which refers to a property that holds on a Zariski dense open set. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19688/what-does-generic-mean-in-algebraic-geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$X$ is generically $\mathcal{P}$" means that there is a dense open subset $U\subset X$ where property $\mathcal{P}$ holds.

Comment: I'm confused. The preimage of a subvariety is still a subvariety, so isn't $f^{-1}(A)$ always reduced?

Comment: @FredericChopin No - consider for instance the map $\Bbb A^1\to\Bbb A^1$ by $x\mapsto x^2$. Then the preimage of $0$ under this map is $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^2)$, which is not reduced.